# mysql replace last group of digits in IP address

Tags: mysql

I would like to replace the last digits of all IP:port's with a *.

For example: `192.168.1.1:2000` should become `192.168.1.*:2000`

Comment: I suggest you do that outside of mysql, like in php or any other language you know to get ip in a loop, using . as a delimiter, change it and set the new value to the table where column like '%192.168.1.1:200%' . But do it outside of mysql to run your loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @ip = '192.168.1.1:2000';
select concat(
    substring_index(substring_index(@ip, ':', 1), '.', 3),
    '.*:',
    substring_index(@ip, ':', -1)
);
```

If you want to understand how it works run the following query:

```
set @ip = '192.168.1.1:2000';
select @ip
    , substring_index(@ip, ':', 1)
    , substring_index(@ip, ':', -1)
    , substring_index(substring_index(@ip, ':', 1), '.', 3);
```

It will return

```
192.168.1.1  2000  192.168.1
```

You just need to concatenate the last two columns and the middle part (`.*:`)